# How to multi columns group linq in c#

Tags: linq

I have list as below:

```
Health_Plan  HealthMemberType_Name   Health_Benefit_Description     

Silver       Parent                  a1     
Silver       Spouse                  b1     
Silver       Children                c1     
Silver       Parent                  a2         
Silver       Spouse                  b2    
Silver       Children                c2    
Gold         Parent                  a1    
Gold         Spouse                  b1
Gold         Children                c1
Gold         Parent                  a2
Gold         Spouse                  b2
Gold         Children                c2
```

I expect to get the following result, (group by Health_Plan  and HealthMemberType_Name)

```
Silver 
   Parent 
       a1     
       a2 
   Spouse 
       b1
       b2

   Children
       c1
       c2

Gold     
   Parent
       a1
       a2

   Spouse            
       b1
       b2

   Children            
       c1
       c2
```

tried codes below:

```
var _aBenefits = _lHealthBenefit.GroupBy(o1 => new { o1.Health_Plan_Pid, o1.Health_Plan }).Select(grp1 => new Health_Benefits_Consolidated
                                    {
                                        Health_Plan_Pid = grp1.Key.Health_Plan_Pid,
                                        Health_Plan = grp1.Key.Health_Plan,
                                        Health_Benefits = grp1.ToList()
                                    }).ToList();

     public class Health_Benefits
    {
        public long Health_Plan_Pid { get; set; }
        public string Health_Plan { get; set; }
        public string Health_Benefit_Description { get; set; }
        public double Health_MaxLimit { get; set; }
        public string HealthMemberType_Name { get; set; }
        public string CCY { get; set; }
        public int Max_Member { get; set; }
    }

    public class Health_Benefits_Consolidated
    {
        public long Health_Plan_Pid { get; set; }
        public string Health_Plan { get; set; }
        public int Max_Member { get; set; }
        public List<Health_Benefits> Health_Benefits { get; set; }
    }
```

looks like I have to group "HealthMemberType_Name" into List.. but I don't know how to insert group to "Health_Benefits = grp1.ToList()"

any help appreciated..

thanks a lot in advance

Regards
Don

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group your input items into groups of input items that have the same `HealthPlan`.

The elements of each group must be grouped into subgroups, where every element of a subgroup has the `HealthMemberTypeName`.

The elements of each subgroup are the `HealthBenefitDescriptions` of this `Group - SubGroup`

For this we use a GroupBy inside another GroupBy. We use the [Enumerable.GroupBy overload that has a resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__)

```
var results = myInputSequence.GroupBy(

    // parameter KeySelector: make groups of inputItems that have equal HealthPlan
    inputItem => inputItem.HealthPlan,

    // parameter resultSelector: take the common HealthPlan, and all input items
    // that have this Healthplan to make a new object:
    (healthPlan, inputItemsWithThisHealthPlan) => new
    {
        HealthPlan = healthPlan,

        // Subgroups: take all input items with this healthplan, and group by
        // HealthMemberTypeName
        HealthMembers = inputItemsWithThisHealthPlan.GroupBy(

            // keySelector:
            inputItemWithThisHealthPlan => inputItemWithThisHealthPlan.HealthMemberTypeName,

            // ResultSelector: take the common HealthMemberTypeName and all
            // input items with this HealthPlan and this HealthMemberTypeName
            // to make one new object
            (healthMemberTypeName, inputItemsWithThisHealthMemberTypeName) => new
            {
                HealthMemberTypeName = healthMemberTypeName,

                // keep only the HealthBenefitDescriptions:
                HealthBenefitDescriptions = inputItemsWithThisHealthMemberTypeName
                   .Select(inputItemWithThisHealthMemberTypeName => inputItemsWithThisHealthMemberTypeName.HealthBenefitDescription)
                   .ToList(),
            })
            .ToList(),
       });
```

The long identifier names might make it difficult to read, but I thought it would help you to understand better what is in it than if I had used x, y, z. Plurals are sequences, singulars are elements of these sequences

Comment: Hi.. in my case, I thought it is only need to group Health_Benefits = grp1.ToList() .. how to group it inside the following:

var _aBenefits = _lHealthBenefit.GroupBy(o1 => new { o1.Health_Plan_Pid, o1.Health_Plan }).Select(grp1 => new Health_Benefits_Consolidated
                                    {
                                        Health_Plan_Pid = grp1.Key.Health_Plan_Pid,
                                        Health_Plan = grp1.Key.Health_Plan,
                                        Health_Benefits = grp1.ToList()
                                    }).ToList();